# Samba Share - Path not found on Windows Client

Tags: networking, server, samba

I'm not entirely sure if this is a problem with my samba configuration or my windows machine:

I just setup a samba share with following configuration:

```
smbd.conf:
[share]
Comment = Raid0 array share
Path = /mnt/md0/share
browseable = Yes
writeable = Yes
guest only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
force user = kalim
force group = kalim


/mnt/md0$ ls -la
drwxrwxr-x+ 7 kalim kalim  4096 Nov 15 19:15 share
```

Windows can find my homeserver but can't connect to it.

> Errorcode: 0X80070035
>   Networkpath not found

Comment: Edit your original post and add the output of the following command - without quotes: "getfacl /mnt/md0/share"

Comment: Did you try to connect using a name or IP adress?